# pandas DataFrame and Yahoo Finance API

Tags: python-2.7, api, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I am trying to use the Yahoo Finance API to read data into a DataFrame.  However when I read values for a symbol from a list they end up in a single column in the DataTable.  I am using the API because I actually want data such as dividend, P/E and I don't think you can access these with datareader.  I have two questions:

1. How do I get values from a list to map to columns in a DataFrame
   (instead of rows)
2. How would I accomplish what I am trying to do for a list for stock symbols

   ```
   import urllib2
   from pandas import DataFrame
   def get_data2(symbol):
       columns = ['last','date','change','high','low','vol']    
       url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=sl1d1c1hgv" % symbol
       file =urllib2.urlopen(url)    
       s = file.read()
       file.close()
       s= s.strip()
       L = s.split(',')
       L[0] = L[0].replace('"','')
       L[2] = L[2].replace('"','')
       D = DataFrame(L, columns=columns)
       return D
   ```

With this code I get a ValueError because the shapes don't match, but essentially  I want to read each value from the list into a column in the DataTable, and eventually iterate over a list of symbols.

Thanks for any help

Comment: why don't you want to use `pandas_datareader`, which is designed for that?

Comment: I think you can only get price and volume data from datareader.  I am not able to find documentation for collecting other statistics.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37797875/5741205) is an example of customized statistics

Comment: Awesome Max, thanks.  I just wonder where there is some comprehensive documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
In [23]: from pandas_datareader import data

In [24]: data.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', '2016-06-01', '2016-06-13')
Out[24]:
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Volume   Adj Close
Date
2016-06-01  734.530029  737.210022  730.659973  734.150024  1250800  734.150024
2016-06-02  732.500000  733.020020  724.169983  730.400024  1337600  730.400024
2016-06-03  729.270020  729.489990  720.559998  722.340027  1222700  722.340027
2016-06-06  724.909973  724.909973  714.609985  716.549988  1565300  716.549988
2016-06-07  719.840027  721.979980  716.549988  716.650024  1336200  716.650024
2016-06-08  723.960022  728.570007  720.580017  728.280029  1582100  728.280029
2016-06-09  722.869995  729.539978  722.335999  728.580017   985900  728.580017
2016-06-10  719.469971  725.890015  716.429993  719.409973  1206000  719.409973
```

[Demo for building pandas Panel when pulling data for multiple tickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756392/missing-a-loop-to-write-a-file/37763947#37763947)

[Demo for pulling custom Yahoo quotes (for example: `Market Cap`, `Div Yield`, `EPS Est Next Quarter`, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794874/pause-url-request-downloads/37797875#37797875)